# How to check the status of the current listener in your database server?oracle

Tags: database, oracle11g

How to check the status of the current listener in your database server?
in oracle

Answer (score 12):

run

```
lsnrctl status
```

More details in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/lsnrctl.htm